# Conflict of same individuals property and datatype property

Tags: ontology, protege, pellet

I am having a problem with "same individuals property" in protege, when I run a reasoner (pellet 1.5 or fact++)

Lets take ontology example

thing has class sons A and B, A has sons C and D.

B, C and D have individuals of the same class.

Can't I say a individual C is "same individual" as individual B, and then add also individual D is "same individual" as individual B? Which is true, they have different names, but they are same individual.

Why does it only work when I set individual B has "same individual" of type C or D?

The protege error is "InconsistentOntologyException:Fact++.Kernel: inconsistent Ontology" and pellet says ontology is inconsistent.

EDIT: Seems its a more deep rooted problem, this example works, going to keep checking.

EDIT2: After some more experimenting, seems its a conflict with DataType properties.
They all share a DataType properties with same name. In the example domain of property would be A and range string. Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you solved it - you were confusing labels (what you call things) with identity: an instance of a class is unique (you can attach different labels to it - i.e. call it different things) but the instance itself can only exist once - and in your example you effectively asserted that there are "three instances of the same instance"...which, of course, doesn't make any sense.